# How to display my web xml database file in my webpage using hashmap

Tags: java, xml

I have a web xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_11" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
    <object class="java.util.HashMap">
        <void method="put">
            <string>productName</string>
            <string>desc</string>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
            <string>productName2</string>
            <string>desc2</string>
        </void>
        <void method="put">
            <string>productName3</string>
            <string>desc3</string>
        </void>
    </object>
</java>
```

My problem is the hashmap is not looping, it only displays the first item in the web xml file. Here is my code for display part..

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\products.xml"));
XMLDecoder xmlDecoder = new XMLDecoder(bis);
HashMap<String, String> productsxml = (HashMap<String, String>) xmlDecoder.readObject();

for (String key : productsxml.keySet())
{
    out.print(key + " " + productsxml.get(key));
}
```

I hope someone could help me figure out why the iteration over the hash keys is not working.

Comment: I think the code is correct. I tried it and the loop goes through all 3 elements. Only one line is printed though, because you are using "print".